# Passing Env Values to Helm to create metricbeat

Tags: kubernetes-helm, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I am using managed ElasticCloud in Azure. I need to install metricbeats using helm charts on AKS. To configure these beats I need to give elastic cloud details like -- cloud.id and cloud.auth. I want pass this values from github environment.

To do so, I added this variables as secrets in Github environment.

This is how my values.yaml looks like:

```
daemonset:
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
  affinity: {}
  enabled: true
  envFrom: []
  extraEnvs: []
  extraVolumes: []
  extraVolumeMounts: []
  hostAliases: []
  hostNetworking: false
  
  metricbeatConfig:
    metricbeat.yml: |
      metricbeat.modules:
      - module: kubernetes
        metricsets:
          - container
          - node
          - pod
          - system
          - volume
        period: 10s
        host: "${NODE_NAME}"
        hosts: ["https://${NODE_NAME}:10250"]
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        ssl.verification_mode: "none"
        
        processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
      - module: kubernetes
        enabled: true
        metricsets:
          - event
      - module: system
        period: 10s
        metricsets:
          - cpu
          - load
          - memory
          - network
          - process
          - process_summary
        processes: ['.*']
        process.include_top_n:
          by_cpu: 5
          by_memory: 5
      - module: system
        period: 1m
        metricsets:
          - filesystem
          - fsstat
        processors:
        - drop_event.when.regexp:
            system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|host|lib)($|/)'
      cloud.id: elk:ZWFzdHVzLmF6dXJlLmVsYXN0aWMtY2xvdWQuY29tOjQ0MyRmZjI5MjNjYTNkNTI0Yzg1ODBiMDk0ZGQxNTRmODQ5ZSQ3MmEyYjY5OTdjMWQ0ODFjYTViYjlkZTY3OGIxMzAzZA==
      cloud.auth: elastic:jixuoLFqs0vneFNaByIQdtL9
      output.elasticsearch:
        protocol: https
        ssl.verification_mode: "none"

  nodeSelector: {}
  
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
    privileged: false
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "100m"
      memory: "100Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "1000m"
      memory: "200Mi"
  tolerations: []

deployment:
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
  affinity: {}
  enabled: true
  envFrom: []
  
  extraEnvs: []
  
  extraVolumes: []
 
  extraVolumeMounts: []
  
  hostAliases: []
  
  metricbeatConfig:
    metricbeat.yml: |
      metricbeat.modules:
      - module: kubernetes
        enabled: true
        metricsets:
          - state_node
          - state_deployment
          - state_replicaset
          - state_pod
          - state_container
        period: 10s
        hosts: ["${KUBE_STATE_METRICS_HOSTS}"]
      cloud.id: elk:ZWFzdHVzLmF6dXJlLmVsYXN0aWMtY2xvdWQuY29tOjQ0MyRmZjI5MjNjYTNkNTI0Yzg1ODBiMDk0ZGQxNTRmODQ5ZSQ3MmEyYjY5OTdjMWQ0ODFjYTViYjlkZTY3OGIxMzAzZA==
      cloud.auth: elastic:jixuoLFqs0vneFNaByIQdtL9
      output.elasticsearch:
        protocol: https
        ssl.verification_mode: "none"

  nodeSelector: {}
  secretMounts: []
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
    privileged: false
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "100m"
      memory: "100Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "1000m"
      memory: "200Mi"
  tolerations: []

replicas: 1

extraContainers: ""

extraInitContainers: ""

hostPathRoot: /var/lib

image: "docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat"
imageTag: "7.17.3"
imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
imagePullSecrets: []

livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash -e
        curl --fail 127.0.0.1:5066
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5

readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash -e
        metricbeat test output
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5

managedServiceAccount: true

clusterRoleRules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes
      - namespaces
      - events
      - pods
      - services
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["extensions"]
    resources:
      - replicasets
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources:
      - statefulsets
      - deployments
      - replicasets
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes/stats
    verbs: ["get"]
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes/stats
    verbs:
      - get
  - nonResourceURLs:
      - "/metrics"
    verbs:
      - get

podAnnotations:
  {}
serviceAccount: ""

serviceAccountAnnotations:
  {}

terminationGracePeriod: 30

priorityClassName: ""

updateStrategy: RollingUpdate

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

kube_state_metrics:
  enabled: true
  host: ""

secrets: []

secret:
  name: elastic
data:
  cloud.id: elk:ZWFzdHVzLmF6dXJlLmVsYXN0aWMtY2xvdWQuY29tOjQ0MyRmZjI5MjNjYTNkNTI0Yzg1ODBiMDk0ZGQxNTRmODQ5ZSQ3MmEyYjY5OTdjMWQ0ODFjYTViYjlkZTY3OGIxMzAzZA==
  cloud.auth: elastic:jixuoLFqs0vneFNaByIQdtL9
```

under templates folder -
secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secret.name }}
type: Opaque
data:
  CLOUD_ID: {{ .Values.data.cloud.id }}
  CLOUD_AUTH: {{ .Values.data.cloud.auth }}
```

and passing it in deployment.yaml and daemonset.yaml as --

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: '{{ template "metricbeat.fullname" . }}-metrics'
  labels:
    app: '{{ template "metricbeat.fullname" . }}-metrics'
    chart: '{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}'
    heritage: '{{ .Release.Service }}'
    release: '{{ .Release.Name }}'
    {{- if .Values.deployment.labels }}
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.deployment.labels }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- else }}
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.labels }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- if .Values.deployment.annotations}}
  annotations:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.deployment.annotations }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: '{{ template "metricbeat.fullname" . }}-metrics'
      release: '{{ .Release.Name }}'
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        {{- range $key, $value := .Values.podAnnotations }}
        {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
        {{- end }}
        {{/* This forces a restart if the configmap has changed */}}
        {{- if or  .Values.metricbeatConfig .Values.deployment.metricbeatConfig }}
        configChecksum: {{ include (print .Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum | trunc 63 }}
        {{- end }}
      labels:
        app: '{{ template "metricbeat.fullname" . }}-metrics'
        chart: '{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}'
        release: '{{ .Release.Name }}'
        {{- if .Values.deployment.labels }}
        {{- range $key, $value := .Values.deployment.labels }}
        {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- else }}
        {{- range $key, $value := .Values.labels }}
        {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
    spec:
      affinity: {{ toYaml .Values.deployment.affinity | nindent 8 }}
      nodeSelector: {{ toYaml .Values.deployment.nodeSelector | nindent 8 }}
      tolerations: {{ toYaml ( .Values.tolerations | default .Values.deployment.tolerations ) | nindent 8 }}
      {{- if .Values.priorityClassName }}
      priorityClassName: {{ .Values.priorityClassName  }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ template "metricbeat.serviceAccount" . }}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ .Values.terminationGracePeriod }}
      {{- if .Values.deployment.hostAliases }}
      hostAliases: {{ toYaml .Values.deployment.hostAliases | nindent 6 }}
      {{- end }}
      volumes:
      {{- range .Values.secretMounts | default .Values.deployment.secretMounts }}
      - name: {{ .name }}
        secret:
          secretName: {{ .secretName }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.metricbeatConfig }}
      - name: metricbeat-config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: {{ template "metricbeat.fullname" . }}-config
      {{- else if .Values.deployment.metricbeatConfig }}
      - name: metricbeat-config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: {{ template "metricbeat.fullname" . }}-deployment-config
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.extraVolumes | default .Values.deployment.extraVolumes }}
{{ toYaml ( .Values.extraVolumes | default .Values.deployment.extraVolumes ) | indent 6 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
{{ toYaml .Values.imagePullSecrets | indent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.extraInitContainers }}
      initContainers:
{{ tpl .Values.extraInitContainers . | indent 6 }}
      {{- end }}
      containers:
      - name: "metricbeat"
        image: "{{ .Values.image }}:{{ .Values.imageTag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: "{{ .Values.imagePullPolicy }}"
        args:
        {{- if index .Values "metricbeatConfig" "kube-state-metrics-metricbeat.yml" }}
          - "-c"
          - "/usr/share/metricbeat/kube-state-metrics-metricbeat.yml"
        {{- end }}
          - "-e"
          - "-E"
          - "http.enabled=true"
        livenessProbe:
{{ toYaml .Values.livenessProbe | indent 10 }}
        readinessProbe:
{{ toYaml .Values.readinessProbe | indent 10 }}
        resources: {{ toYaml ( .Values.resources | default .Values.deployment.resources ) | nindent 10 }}
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: KUBE_STATE_METRICS_HOSTS
          {{- if .Values.kube_state_metrics.enabled }}
          value: "$({{ .Release.Name | replace "-" "_" | upper }}_KUBE_STATE_METRICS_SERVICE_HOST):$({{ .Release.Name | replace "-" "_" | upper }}_KUBE_STATE_METRICS_SERVICE_PORT_HTTP)"
          {{- else }}
          value: {{ .Values.kube_state_metrics.host | default "kube-state-metrics:8080"}}
          {{- end }}
        - name: cloud.id
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: {{ .Values.secret.name }}
              key: CLOUD_ID
        - name: cloud.auth
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: {{ .Values.secret.name }}
              key: CLOUD_AUTH

{{- if .Values.extraEnvs | default .Values.deployment.extraEnvs }}
{{ toYaml ( .Values.extraEnvs | default .Values.deployment.extraEnvs ) | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
        envFrom: {{ toYaml ( .Values.envFrom | default .Values.deployment.envFrom ) | nindent 10 }}
        securityContext: {{ toYaml ( .Values.podSecurityContext | default .Values.deployment.securityContext ) | nindent 10 }}
        volumeMounts:
        {{- range .Values.secretMounts | default .Values.deployment.secretMounts }}
        - name: {{ .name }}
          mountPath: {{ .path }}
          {{- if .subPath }}
          subPath: {{ .subPath }}
          {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- range $path, $config := .Values.metricbeatConfig }}
        - name: metricbeat-config
          mountPath: /usr/share/metricbeat/{{ $path }}
          readOnly: true
          subPath: {{ $path }}
        {{ else }}
        {{- range $path, $config := .Values.deployment.metricbeatConfig }}
        - name: metricbeat-config
          mountPath: /usr/share/metricbeat/{{ $path }}
          readOnly: true
          subPath: {{ $path }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.extraVolumeMounts | default .Values.deployment.extraVolumeMounts }}
{{ toYaml ( .Values.extraVolumeMounts | default .Values.deployment.extraVolumeMounts ) | indent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.extraContainers }}
{{ tpl .Values.extraContainers . | indent 6 }}
      {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and this is how I am executing helm:

```
helm upgrade --install mbeat elastic/metricbeat --version 7.17.3 -f ./values.yaml --set cloud.id=${{ secrets.CLOUD_ID }},cloud.auth=${{ secrets.CLOUD_AUTH }}
```

But it is still taking the value of cloud.id and cloud.auth given in values.yaml its not using what I setting through helm upgrade install command

[image]

Comment: not sure why in values.yaml you have `cloud.id: { .Values.cloud.id }` generally values.yaml store the values. also in env section of deloyment.yaml you are passing `secretKeyRef` with key only there is no `secret-name`

Comment: Thanks @Harsh for the suggestions. I made the changes and edited the snippet above.
I gave some random values for my variables in values.yaml and secret.yaml which I hope to get replaced by the values which I am passing from command line while executing helm upgrade.

But still this do not work as it is considering the random values which I gave

Comment: that's weird could you please share the command you are running so can get the more idea.

Comment: helm upgrade --install mbeat elastic/metricbeat --version 7.17.3 -f ./values.yaml --set cloud.id="actualCloudId",cloud.auth="actualCloudAuth"

Comment: helm upgrade --install mbeat elastic/metricbeat --version 7.17.3 -f ./values.yaml --set cloud.id=actualCloudId --set cloud.auth=actualCloudAuth

Comment: No this also do not work. still taking old values.

Comment: helm upgrade --install mbeat elastic/metricbeat --reset-values --version 7.17.3 -f ./values.yaml --set cloud.id=actualCloudId --set cloud.auth=actualCloudAuth

Comment: No harsh.. this is not working.. I am not sure if I am missing something in the yaml files..

Comment: looks like your template having issues and wrong values getting injected and --set is not able to overwrite value due to template issues.

Comment: give me few min will share proper helm and template details. coz i am not sure how you are planning to overwrite the `cloud.id: cloudId`

Comment: Sure will wait for your input.. thank you so much

Comment: Somehow I feel the way I have defined in deployment.yaml or daemonset.yaml may not be correct. In values.yaml, cloud.id and cloud.auth are defined under section daemonset.metricbeatConfig and deployment.metricbeatConfig. (see the values.yaml above)

Also if i set the values for clou.id and cloud.auth from commandLine, how will it understand it has to look under daemonset and deployment section to replace the variable.

Comment: Yes you are right will share the proper details once and example you can copy paste meanwhile if possible please modify question or anything thay need update or command you are running so i can replicate and check in hour will sit on it

Comment: from where this error is coming ? `.Values.cloud.id` I can't see anywhere above in file.

Answer (score 0):

You generate secret file will be something like

**template/secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secret.name }}
data:
  CLOUD_ID: {{ .Values.data.cloud_id }}
```

this is your **values.yaml**

```
replicaCount: 1

secret:
  name: common

data:
  cloud_id: "xyz"
  username: "user"
  password: "admin123"
```

So values from **values.yaml** gets applied to the secret and the template got created.

The error mentioned in question: `Exiting: error loading config file: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.cloud.id":interface {}(nil)}`

I am not able to find the `.Values.cloud.id` that you have used which throws an error.

**values.yaml**

```
daemonset:
  metricbeatConfig:
    metricbeat.yml:
      metricbeat.modules:
        - module: kubernetes
          enabled: true
          metricsets:
            - state_node
            - state_deployment
            - state_replicaset
            - state_pod
            - state_container
          period: 10s
          hosts: ["${KUBE_STATE_METRICS_HOSTS}"]
        cloud.id: cloudId
```

**secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: secret
metadata:
  name: secret-name
data:
{{- $root := . -}}
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.daemonset.metricbeatConfig }}
  {{- if $key | regexMatch ".*\\.ya?ml$" }}
  {{ $key }}: |
{{ toYaml $value | default "{}" | indent 4 }}
  {{- else }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ toYaml $value | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

it will create secret something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: secret
metadata:
  name: secret-name
data:
  metricbeat.yml: |
      metricbeat.modules:
        - module: kubernetes
          enabled: true
          metricsets:
            - state_node
            - state_deployment
            - state_replicaset
            - state_pod
            - state_container
          period: 10s
          hosts: ["${KUBE_STATE_METRICS_HOSTS}"]
        cloud.id: cloudId
```

if you trying to get the **value** of **cloud.id** from **values.yaml** you can not directly get that as it's part of **metricbeat.yml** file. Do let me know if you are looking for that.

**Update :**

**values.yaml**

```
secret:
  name: elastic

data:
  cloud_id: elk:ZWFzdHVzLmF6dXJlLmVsYXN0aWMtY2xvdWQuY29tOjQ0MyRmZjI5MjNjYTNkNTI0Yzg1ODBiMDk0ZGQxNTRmODQ5ZSQ3MmEyYjY5OTdjMWQ0ODFjYTViYjlkZTY3OGIxMzAzZA==
  cloud_auth: elastic:jixuoLFqs0vneFNaByIQdtL9
```

**secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secret.name }}
type: Opaque
data:
  CLOUD_ID: {{ .Values.data.cloud_id }}
  CLOUD_AUTH: {{ .Values.data.cloud_auth }}
```

**command**

```
 helm template testschart --version 1.0.2 --output-dir ./yaml . --debug --set data.cloud_id="asdfasf"
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your time and effort and going extra mile in helping me out in this. 
I tried what you suggested, now the issue is it is still taking the value of cloud.id and cloud.auth from  values.yaml. I want to use the values which I am setting through helm command. I have edited the question with full.

I feel the way it is being referred in deployment.yaml is wrong. Not sure

Comment: Sure no worries got your point overwriting the template value with yaml no issues give me few min will get back.

Comment: you can not update the values to secret like in the command that's mistake, we overwrite the value mostly in values.yaml `hierarchy` so `helm upgrade --install mbeat elastic/metricbeat --version 7.17.3 -f ./values.yaml --set data.cloud.id=YOUR-VALUE,data.cloud.auth=$THIS_WILL_TAKE_FROM_ENV`

Comment: I tried setting the value through this command, but still its trying to connect through the cloud.id given originally in values.yaml. Its not resetting.

If you see under deployment/daemonset section in values.yaml, there we give cloud.id and cloud.auth (just before output.elasticsearch). I am confused how this value will be replaced. Ideally if this reset, then things should work. How will this section know that it has to be set to new value.

Comment: or the other thing, the way I am referencing in deployment.yaml may be wrong. Should be reference as i am doing in env section or elsewhere? Clueless

Comment: the updated answer, dot in values.yaml might be creating issue,

Comment: cloud.id and cloud.auth is standard attribute from elastic. it identifies the using this variable. I fear i can change that

Comment: Keep it as it in secret you will be injecting in deployment right but in values.yaml you can anything right ? What matter is what we are injecting with secret actually to deployment

Comment: i changed values.yaml to cloud_id and i kept secrets.yaml and deployment as it is..
but as per crashed pods I see that, it is still trying to connect to the old one..

Comment: That could be some other issue secret not updated or so

Comment: secrets i have kept as you asked.